# Changing all toggle's states (on/off) with 2 buttons

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchos

I am new to the **WatchOS** world and because of that I am in need of some help getting past a point where, even with tutorials, I seem to not be able to do what I am needing to do.

I have a simple **watchOS** app. Basically its a **list** with **toggles** and **2 buttons**. What I am wanting to do is, when clicking on said button, have all the toggles **change to "off" state**. Likewise, the other button will put them all to the **"on" state**.

Here is my code so far (some code was removed):

```
import SwiftUI

struct User: Decodable {
    var theID: String
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var isOn: Bool
}

var body: some View {
    List{
        ForEach($users, id: \.theID) { $item in
            HStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) {
                    Label {
                        Text(item.description)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 85)
                            .frame(maxHeight: 100)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    } icon: {
                        if item.name == "J" {
                            Image("imgJayden")
                                .scaledToFill()
                            
                        } else if item.name == "T" {
                            Image("imgTab")
                                .scaledToFill()
                        } else {
                            Image("imgBoth")
                                .scaledToFill()
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: item.isOn) { value in
                        if (rndCnt == 0) {
                            if (value) {
                                //print("tunning on")
                                sendJsonData(a: item.theID, b: item.name, c: item.description, d: item.isOn)
                            } else {
                                //print("turning off")
                                sendJsonData(a: item.theID, b: item.name, c: item.description, d: item.isOn)
                            }
                            
                            rndCnt = 1
                        } else {
                            rndCnt = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(2)
        }
        List{
            HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 50){
                Button {
                    }label: {
                        Image("on")
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("turned all on!")
                    }
                Button {
                    }label: {
                        Image("off")
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("turned all off!")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: loadData)
}
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.1:81/data.php?data=ALL") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                
                if let decodedResponse = try?
                    decoder.decode([User].self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decodedResponse
                    }
                    
                    return
                }
            }
            
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error....")")
        }.resume()
    }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

For my list I have the `.onAppear(perform: loadData)` which is what populates the toggles with the data (thats in function loadData. Now I'm at a standstill on how to **loop through all** the **toggles** and set them all to either **on** or **off** depending on which button was pressed.

Would be great if someone could help me out on this!

Comment: onChange of the button’s variable

Comment: @loremipsum Mind showing me that in code? It needs to switch them programmatically and not by the user. I understand the onChange part but not sure how to call each toggle to make them all on or all off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `onTapGesture` for the `Button`, they don't need it they are buttons.
Use this example code to turn all users `Toggle` on/off.

```
 List{
     HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 50){
         Button {
             print("turned all on!")
             users.indices.forEach { users[$0].isOn = true } // <-- here
             // alternative
             // for i in users.indices { users[i].isOn = true }
         }label: {
             Image("on")
                 .scaledToFill()
                 .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
         }
         Button {
             print("turned all off!")
             users.indices.forEach { users[$0].isOn = false }  // <-- here
         }label: {
             Image("off")
                 .scaledToFill()
                 .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
         }
     }.buttonStyle(.bordered)  // <-- here
 }
```